# Connect Hip Bone to the Tail of Backbone

Tags: rigging, armature

Hi so I know how to connect bones but in this case I'm not sure how to get it working. I want to be able to be able to drag the whole mesh along an axis, but can't because the hips are not connected to the backbone. The armature kind of splits up. I want to parent both hip bones to the end of the backbone. If I try parenting the child bone the regular way, I get what is shown in the picture below. Anyone know how to solve this? [image]

File Link:
[image]

Comment: A child bone does not have to be directly connected to it's parent. See the "connected" property under bone relations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Sambler eluded to, parent the hip bones to the backbone without being connected.  This is also known as 'Keep Offset'.

1. Get into Bone Edit mode.
2. Select Hip_L/Hip_R bone.
3. Select Backbone.
4. Hit `Ctrl+P` and from the menu select `Keep Offset`.
   [image]

Here's the result of the above steps, repeated for both hips.

[image]